# extract noun-chunk from single token

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Consider this simple example

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

  doc = nlp('the angry programmer wrote a nice stackover question to another angry programmer')

for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk)
the angry programmer
a nice stackover question
another angry programmer
```

I am interested in writing a function that returns, for every token, the noun-chunk that (may) include that token.

Something like:

```
for tok in doc:
    print(tok, func_get_noun_chunk(tok))


the, the angry programmer
angry, the angry programmer
programmer, the angry programmer
wrote,
...
```

How can I do that in Spacy? Of course, the issue is that there could be multiple noun chunks containing the same tokens. I need to return the right one!

Thanks!

Comment: does this answer your question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307452/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-whole-noun-chunk-using-a-root-token-in-spacy

Comment: not really, because I need the exact noun chunk that contains a token. There could be multiple noun chunks in the same sentence, each with similar words.

Comment: question edited for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to build a list of all of the noun chunks, then loop over the tokens and build up a list of the tokens and noun chunk pairs:

```
noun_chunks = [nc for nc in doc.noun_chunks]
token_chunks = list()
for tok in doc:
    for nc in noun_chunks:
        if tok.i >= nc.start and tok.i < nc.end:
            token_chunks.append((tok, nc))
            break
print(token_chunks)
```

Outputs

```
[(the, the angry programmer),
 (angry, the angry programmer),
 (programmer, the angry programmer),
 (a, a nice stackover question),
 (nice, a nice stackover question),
 (stackover, a nice stackover question),
 (question, a nice stackover question),
 (another, another angry programmer),
 (angry, another angry programmer),
 (programmer, another angry programmer)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a membership test.

First, our imports and `doc` creation:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens.doc import Doc
from spacy.tokens.span import Span
from typing import Union, Tuple

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp('the angry programmer wrote a nice stackover question to another angry programmer')
```

Approach 1:

```
def approach_1(doclike: Union[Doc, Span]) -> None:
    for token in doclike:
        print(token, next((noun_chunk for noun_chunk in doclike.noun_chunks if token in noun_chunk), None))
```

However, we can see that this is not an ideal approach, since we loop over the `noun_chunks` for each `token`.

```
%%timeit
approach_1(doc)

112 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Instead, as Matthew Cox suggests, we should save the `noun_chunks`.

```
def approach_2(doclike: Union[Doc, Span]) -> None:
    noun_chunks: Tuple = (*(stack_overflow_doc.noun_chunks),)
    for token in doclike:
        for noun_chunk in noun_chunks:
            if token in noun_chunk:
                print(token, noun_chunk)
            else:
                print(token)
```

This gives us noticeably better performance, time-wise:

```
%%timeit
approach_2(doc)

29.6 µs ± 1.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

However, I don't suggest either approach if you plan to perform this operation many times on the same `doc`. Instead, provide the tokens with a custom `noun_chunk` attribute. By doing so, you will incur a set-up cost, but subsequent queries ought to be cheaper.

```
Token.set_extension('noun_chunk', default=None)

%%timeit
for noun_chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    for token in noun_chunk:
        token._.noun_chunk = noun_chunk

25.2 µs ± 736 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
def approach_3(doclike: Union[Doc, Span]) -> None:
    for token in doclike:
        print(token, token._.noun_chunk)
```

```
%%timeit
approach_3(doc)

21 µs ± 262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Consider then [adding a custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) to add the `noun_chunk` attribute during initial `doc` creation.

---

**EDIT:** Matthew's approach seems faster for this example. His method, combined with a pipeline component, is probably what you're looking for.